# How do I update a task from a custom InfoPath form

Tags: workflow, infopath, task-list

We are in the process of figuring out how to use SharePoint and InfoPath to replace our current Workflow system. And I’m running through some test scenario’s/examples and have run into a problem.

I’m currently stuck with getting a task updated from an InfoPath form.
Here’s what I’ve done so far.

I created an InfoPath form for my example workflow, an IT request form for hardware, software etc. I then created a SharePoint library and associated the InfoPath form. I created a state machine workflow project in Visual studio and associated to the library. I built a simple workflow with a task assignment.

The default task form worked fine but we wanted to use a view of our InfoPath form. So I serialised the InfoPath form into my VS project, and added the form to the Project. We managed to get the InfoPath form showing instead of the default task form. So far so good.

The problem I now have is that whilst the InfoPath form shows when the task is opened, there doesn't appear to be any way of updating the actual task. The OnTaskChanged event therefore doesn't fire in the state machine workflow.
I didn't want to use the InfoPath ribbon controls for submitting or saving so I hid them and added buttons for approve and reject. However these buttons don’t do anything other than close the form or submit a new task to the task list. I can’t figure out how to get the underlying task updated from the button.

Does anyone have any idea’s how I can update the task from my custom form? Or have I gone about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have a 'Submit to the host environment' rule rather than just a close on your button